# Check internet connection in ANDROID

Tags: android, connection

Hello I have application based on data retrieved over internet...

How can I handle my app in case there is no connection available?

I can detect connection with

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

It works fine... But how can I prevent Force Erros when I know there is no connection? I would like a message to be shown - something like: "Sorry! There is no internet connection available!" and not my application to crush...

Comment: Use the method you just mentioned to test if there's internet availability. If there isn't, simply show an AlertDialog and don't try connecting? Not to mention that Socket communication (if that is what you use) should be in try/catch clauses, which means you can simply catch the exceptions. I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
 /**
   * Checks if the device has Internet connection.
   * 
   * @return <code>true</code> if the phone is connected to the Internet.
   */
  public static boolean hasConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) MbridgeApp.getContext().getSystemService(
        Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {
      return true;
    }

    NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()) {
      return true;
    }

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Comment: On the HTC Desire running 2.2.2 there's a bug where getActiveNetworkInfo() always returns null. This code is great because it still works and only falls back to getActiveNetworkInfo() if it needs to.

Comment: +1 for being most bulletproof example I have found for checking network connectivity

Answer (score 4):

getActiveNetworkInfo() may return null, so you will get a force close, but you can do that:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (null == ni)
    return false;
return ni.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Then the check is simple:

```
if (networkAvailable()) // << your method from above
{
// Do stuff
}
else
{
   Toast.makeToast(yourcontext, "No network available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: But when I get this... how can I than just show the message telling No connection available and stop executing the other things:

Comment: @M.V. - See edited answer in a minute

Comment: Thanks, but do I have to put in all Activities or is it enough to put it just in main Activity?

Comment: I don't know the structure of your application, so it's hard to say, but either put it in places where you access the web or if you have one class that handles the connection and returns some string, put it there.

Answer (score 3):

I can't make comment but note that `NetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();` in all the above answers will only tell you if you are connected to router or not but if you are connected to router that don't have internet access then your application will crash because it will through UnknownHostException.
you should add the following catch enclose to your try catch

```
catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    getRequest.abort();
    Log.w("unknownhostexception whicle connects to the host " + url, e);
    }
```

or make timeout for your request what ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to have following permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean connectionAvailable() {
    boolean connected = false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        //we are connected to a network
        connected = true;
    }
    return connected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ConnectivityManager conMgr  = ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
 NetworkInfo info = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo(); 

if(info != null && info.isConnected()) 
{
   // internet is there.
}
else
{
   // internet is not there.
}
```