# Android: Check connection to server

Tags: android, android-service

So I have a method that checks if the device is connected to the internet [based on this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911418/check-internet-connection-in-android)

It works ok, but in a couple of cases I find that although the phone shows being connected to the internet, it still does not have access to my server. What I am really looking to do it check connection to my specific URL.

How could I implement that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
    try{
        URL myUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        connection.connect();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle your exceptions
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will attempt to connect to your server's URL and if it fails, you obviously don't have a connection. ;-)

Comment: your down vote may have been because you specify timeout as a long, but .setConnectTimeout (which you miss-spelled) only accepts an int value.

Comment: I mean, this method should be run background. If not it will trigger NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut)
```

Comment: this method sometimes return false, even host available

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process proc;
            try {
                proc = runtime.exec("ping -c 1"+ (String) getText(R.string.Server));
                proc.waitFor();
                int exit = proc.exitValue();
                if (exit == 0) { // normal exit


                } else { // abnormal exit, so decide that the server is not
                            // reachable


                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // other servers, for example
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```