# Checking Connection to Server in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Just as the title suggest, I have a problem with checking android connection to the server.

I have a project that I left for some month, back then the code that I used to check the server's connection was the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180072/android-check-connection-to-server) question, but now when I opened this project again and try to run it, I can't seem to be able to reach the server.

This is my code to check the server's connection :

```
public static boolean isServerConnected() {
    try {
        URL myUrl = new URL(URL_CONNECTION);
        URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        connection.connect();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is where I call it (in a login button) :

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (Servers.isServerConnected()) {
                username = edtUser.getText().toString();
                password = edtPass.getText().toString();
                login();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server is not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the exception that I got :

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:113)
    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:196)
    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
    at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:367)
    at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:130)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
    at 
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
    at 
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:126)
    at com.itats.huwenakapp.koneksi.Servers.isServerConnected(Servers.java:38)
    at com.itats.huwenakapp.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:74)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
    at 
com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: `problem with checking android connection to the server.` 'The' server? 'A' server you mean? And Android? You mean your Android app i think.

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got  `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` that means you cant check this with your main UI thread. you may have to create a new Thread.

you may check like this in short:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Boolean connected = isServerConnected();
            YourActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if(connected){
                        Log.e("isConnected", connected + " ");
                        //do your stuff
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();


// your found method 
public static boolean isServerConnected() {
    try {
        URL myUrl = new URL(URL_CONNECTION);
        URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        connection.connect();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

make sure `URL_CONNECTION` is properly formatted

Full Example:

```
      btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Boolean connected = isServerConnected();
                    YourActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if (connected) {
                                Log.e("isConnected", connected + " ");
                                //do your stuff
                                username = edtUser.getText().toString();
                                password = edtPass.getText().toString();
                                login();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server is not connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();


        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! this is work like a charm! I still don't understand why back then I don't get this exception tho. Probably because something is deprecated when I left this project

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the exception log you are getting [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException) this occurs when you are performing a network call on Main Thread / UI Thread of android. To resolve this issue you have to perform the call on a background thread. This could include using a [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) (depricated) or [Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines) (only for Kotlin) or [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) or any other threading way to run the the call on background thread.

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-can-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) question for answers.