# Android:While running in my Android device it's working. But I can't figure > out why the same thing is not happening in my emulator

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking internet connection on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086159/checking-internet-connection-on-android)

In my application I want to check internet connection. If the device is not connected to internet I want to close my app. So I use this method for checking the internet connection.

```
public boolean isDeviceConnectedToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

User permissions are set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I turned off my wifi and running the app , I got true in Log cat.

> While running in my Android device it's working. But I can't figure
>   out why the same thing is not happening in my emulator.

Comment: What device you are using? Tablet or Smartphone??

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates of this here on SO.

Comment: [Have a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5911553/940096)

Comment: look at this http://rajareddypolamreddy.blogspot.in/2012/04/checking-for-internet-availability-in.html.

Comment: Better remove your internet cable from your PC(CPU) and try to run. Now, it will give false

Comment: @Keyser If it is duplicate then there is an option to close the question as duplicate.

Comment: @Dharmendra Yes but that option requires a link to the/a duplicate. I don't always have the time to do the job for them.

Comment: @Keyser Actually when you click on the option possible duplicate then it will automatically populate similar questions so you do not require much effort.

Comment: @Dharmendra It will try. Still not required of me in any way. I assure you I'm well aware of the flagging options.

Comment: @Dharmendra and Keyser, It may be the duplicate question but I want the answer for why my emulator cant check the connection , but my android device did.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void checkConnection() throws NoInternetException {
    boolean connected = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = 
            (ConnectivityManager) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (cm != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if ( ni.isConnected() && ni.isAvailable() ) {
                connected = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (! connected) {
        throw new NoInternetException("NO INTERNET CONNECTION");
    }
}
```

Here I'm throwing exception, if there is no network. Anyway you can return varuable **connected**

Comment: I turned off my wifi connection and run the app still i got true in Logcat

Comment: I have a webview in my app, here web page not available window opens

Comment: Sridhar, try to use ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

Comment: JunR, Hey While running the app in my android device it worked, But in my emulator it doesnt make sense

Comment: Sridhar, maybe because there is no wifi in emulator. I don't see it in adb virtual device preferences

Comment: then what should I do for making my emulator also check connection

Answer (score 1):

A Simple Code for Checking Internet Connection.

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

String status = netInfo.getState().toString();
if (status.equals("CONNECTED")) 
{
    //DO you work or return your flag
} 
else 
{
    Log.e("error", "No connection available ");
}
```

Comment: I turned off my wifi connection and run the app still i got true in Logcat. 
I have a webview in my app, here web page not available window opens –